# matching regex of a particular form

Tags: java, regex

I want to match a regex of the following form

```
(hex_number) (anything) constant=(true or false)
```

`anything` can match any printable character or a space or tab. I am programming in java so I was using the following regex:

```
(\\p{Alnum}+) (\\.+) constant=(true|false)
```

The first two matching groups is what I really want. I however do not get a match.

Any ideas?

PS: `Alnum` and `.` are just for simplicity and it is fine that they will match more than what I require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Can't believe I missed this the first time. You want `.`, not `\\.`. Your version matches a literal `.` character.

```
([0-9A-Fa-f]+)\\s(.+)\\sconstant=(true|false)
```

Comment: E. Morgan I tried it now but it still gives the same problem.

Comment: E. Morgan I see my mistake. I will try again.

Comment: @r.v - Glad to help. Sorry I didn't notice this at first; I was so busy looking for something obscure that I didn't notice what was in front of my face! That's probably what you did too. Happens to us all. :)